# [python]: problem about python string literals

Tags: python, backslash

code goes below:

```
line = r'abc\def\n'
rline = re.sub('\\\\', '+', line) # then rline should be r'abc+def+n'
```

Apparently, I just want to replace the backslashes in line with '+'.
What I thought was that a backslash in line can be expressed as '\', then why should I use '\\' to get the re.sub work right.

I'm confused.

Comment: Why not just use `rline = line.replace('\\', '+')`?

Comment: @nagisa -- ya, that's a way circumventing the problem, but I want to know why re.sub doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are two levels of backslashing:

1. re.sub uses \ as an escape
2. Python uses \ as an escape (unless you do r'...')

So `\\\\` (python) -> `\\` (re.sub) -> `\`

EDIT

And the SO level of backslashing! (it got me!)

Comment: +1 for cleverness -1 for not using backticks to format code properly. :P.

Comment: formatted with backticks, doesn't require additional backslashing ;)

Comment: I didn't edit it since he made a point of getting it "right" without.

Comment: @Owen -- It seems like your answer pretty much convince me. Hah.

Comment: and one more question, what do you mean by SO level ?

Comment: @Alcott Stack Overflow also uses \ for escapes.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good habit to *always* use raw strings when dealing with regex patterns:

```
In [45]: re.sub(r'\\', r'+', line)
Out[45]: 'abc+def+n'
```

To answer your question though, Python interprets `'\\\\'` as two backslash characters:

```
In [44]: list('\\\\')
Out[44]: ['\\', '\\']
```

And the rules of regex interpret two backslash characters as one literal backslash.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a literal pattern, not an actual regular expression, you should use both raw strings and [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) to avoid doubling backslashes or any other manual escaping completely.

So, your example would become:

```
line = r'abc\def\n'
backslash = re.escape(r'\')
rline = re.sub(backslash, '+', line)
```

Comment: Hmm, apparently the SO syntax highlighter doesn't like raw strings.